# c ++ CUDA sum of some array elements

Tags: c++, cuda

У меня есть массив из 8 точек (после отладки будет несколько миллионов таких массивов). Мне нужно найти 6 определенных сум этих точек.

Sum of points (0, 1, 2, 3).

Sum of points (0, 1, 4, 5).

Sum of points (1, 2, 5, 6).

Sum of points (2, 3, 6, 7).

Sum of points (7, 0, 3, 4).

Sum of points (4, 5, 6, 7).

Я написал программу, которая, казалось бы (хаха), должна работать, но она не работает. Как я понимаю, что-то с синхронизацией потоков. Но я не понимаю, как решить это правильно и в чем проблема.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>

struct Node {
    double xyz[3];
};

cudaError_t addWithCuda(Node* c, Node* a, unsigned int* order);


unsigned int node_in_face[24] = {0, 3, 2, 1,   ///< Face 0
                                   0, 1, 5, 4,   ///< Face 1 //-V112
                                   1, 2, 6, 5,   ///< Face 2
                                   2, 3, 7, 6,   ///< Face 3
                                   3, 0, 4, 7,   ///< Face 4 //-V112
                                   4, 5, 6, 7};  ///< Face 5 //-V112

__global__ void centroid(Node* nodes_of_value, Node* nodes_centroid, unsigned int* order) {
  int n_centroid = threadIdx.x;
  int n_node     = threadIdx.y;
  int z          = threadIdx.z;
  int n_value    = blockIdx.x;

  nodes_centroid[n_centroid].xyz[z] += nodes_of_value[n_value * 8 + order[n_centroid * 4 + n_node]].xyz[z];
  __syncthreads();

}

int main()
{
    const int arraySize = 8;
    Node nodes[arraySize] = {{0., 0., 0.},
                             {1., 0., 0.},
                             {1., 1., 0.},
                             {0., 1., 0.},
                             {0., 0., 1.},
                             {1., 0., 1.},
                             {1., 1., 1.},
                             {0., 1., 1.}};  // Координаты каждой точки
    Node centroids[6] = {{0., 0., 0.}, 
                         {0., 0., 0.}, 
                         {0., 0., 0.},
                         {0., 0., 0.}, 
                         {0., 0., 0.}, 
                         {0., 0., 0.}};  // 6 пустых точек, куда нужно просуммировать значения

    // Add vectors in parallel.
    cudaError_t cudaStatus = addWithCuda(nodes, centroids, node_in_face);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "addWithCuda failed!");
        return 1;
    }

    printf(
        "{0 = %f, %f, %f}\n"
        "{1 = %f, %f, %f}\n"
        "{2 = %f, %f, %f}\n"
        "{3 = %f, %f, %f}\n"
        "{4 = %f, %f, %f}\n"
        "{5 = %f, %f, %f}\n",
        centroids[0].xyz[0], centroids[0].xyz[1], centroids[0].xyz[2], 
        centroids[1].xyz[0], centroids[1].xyz[1], centroids[1].xyz[2], 
        centroids[2].xyz[0], centroids[2].xyz[1], centroids[2].xyz[2], 
        centroids[3].xyz[0], centroids[3].xyz[1], centroids[3].xyz[2],
        centroids[4].xyz[0], centroids[4].xyz[1], centroids[4].xyz[2], 
        centroids[5].xyz[0], centroids[5].xyz[1], centroids[5].xyz[2]);

    // cudaDeviceReset must be called before exiting in order for profiling and
    // tracing tools such as Nsight and Visual Profiler to show complete traces.
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceReset();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceReset failed!");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

// Helper function for using CUDA to add vectors in parallel.
cudaError_t addWithCuda(Node* nodes, Node* centroids, unsigned int* order)
{
    Node* dev_nodes               = 0;
    Node* dev_centroids           = 0;
    unsigned int* dev_order       = 0;

    cudaError_t cudaStatus;

    // Choose which GPU to run on, change this on a multi-GPU system.
    cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(0);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaSetDevice failed!  Do you have a CUDA-capable GPU installed?");
        goto Error;
    }

    // Allocate GPU buffers for three vectors (two input, one output)    .
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_nodes, 8 * sizeof(Node));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_centroids, 6 * sizeof(Node));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_order, 24 * sizeof(unsigned int));
    if(cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
      fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
      goto Error;
    }

    // Copy input vectors from host memory to GPU buffers.
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_nodes, nodes, 8 * sizeof(Node), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_order, order, 24 * sizeof(unsigned int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if(cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
      fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
      goto Error;
    }

    // Launch a kernel on the GPU with one thread for each element.

    dim3 threadsPerBlock(6, 4, 3);
    centroid<<<1, threadsPerBlock >>>(dev_nodes, dev_centroids, dev_order);

    // Check for any errors launching the kernel
    cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "addKernel launch failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
        goto Error;
    }
    
    // cudaDeviceSynchronize waits for the kernel to finish, and returns
    // any errors encountered during the launch.
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code %d after launching addKernel!\n", cudaStatus);
        goto Error;
    }

    // Copy output vector from GPU buffer to host memory.
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(centroids, dev_centroids, 6 * sizeof(Node), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

Error:
    cudaFree(dev_nodes);
    cudaFree(dev_centroids);
    
    return cudaStatus;
}
```

Comment: `Как я понимаю, что-то с синхронизацией потоков` - опишите конкретно в чем проблема, то что вы написали не информативно

Comment: Сумма получается неправильная. как буд-то не все ячейки просуммировались, а только часть

Comment: @AntonMitrochin мы жаждем подррробностей! Какие были входные данные? Какая сумма должна была получиться? Какая получилась в итоге?

Answer (score 1):

В блоке потоков у вас есть несколько потоков (по y), каждый из которых пытается обновить одно и то же местоположение. CUDA не разбирается в этом автоматически.

Типичным подходом здесь было бы использование атомики, чтобы несколько потоков, добавляемых в одно и то же место, происходили упорядоченным образом.

Поскольку вы используете двойные количества, CUDA обеспечивает только собственное атомарное добавление для устройств с вычислительной мощностью 6.x и выше. В противном случае вы должны использовать метод, приведенный в руководстве по программированию, чтобы обеспечить операцию двойного атомарного добавления. (В качестве альтернативы вы можете переключиться с `double` на `float`).

Вот пример вашего измененного кода, работающего на устройстве cc 7.0:

```
$ cat t1812.cu
#include <stdio.h>

struct Node {
    double xyz[3];
};

cudaError_t addWithCuda(Node* c, Node* a, unsigned int* order);


unsigned int node_in_face[24] = {0, 3, 2, 1,   ///< Face 0
                                   0, 1, 5, 4,   ///< Face 1 //-V112
                                   1, 2, 6, 5,   ///< Face 2
                                   2, 3, 7, 6,   ///< Face 3
                                   3, 0, 4, 7,   ///< Face 4 //-V112
                                   4, 5, 6, 7};  ///< Face 5 //-V112

__global__ void centroid(Node* nodes_of_value, Node* nodes_centroid, unsigned int* order) {
  int n_centroid = threadIdx.x;
  int n_node     = threadIdx.y;
  int z          = threadIdx.z;
  int n_value    = blockIdx.x;

  atomicAdd(&(nodes_centroid[n_centroid].xyz[z]),  nodes_of_value[n_value * 8 + order[n_centroid * 4 + n_node]].xyz[z]);
  __syncthreads();

}

int main()
{
    const int arraySize = 8;
    Node nodes[arraySize] = {{0., 0., 0.},
                             {1., 0., 0.},
                             {1., 1., 0.},
                             {0., 1., 0.},
                             {0., 0., 1.},
                             {1., 0., 1.},
                             {1., 1., 1.},
                             {0., 1., 1.}};  // Координаты каждой точки
    Node centroids[6] = {{0., 0., 0.},
                         {0., 0., 0.},
                         {0., 0., 0.},
                         {0., 0., 0.},
                         {0., 0., 0.},
                         {0., 0., 0.}};  // 6 пустых точек, куда нужно просуммировать значения

    // Add vectors in parallel.
    cudaError_t cudaStatus = addWithCuda(nodes, centroids, node_in_face);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "addWithCuda failed!");
        return 1;
    }

    printf(
        "{0 = %f, %f, %f}\n"
        "{1 = %f, %f, %f}\n"
        "{2 = %f, %f, %f}\n"
        "{3 = %f, %f, %f}\n"
        "{4 = %f, %f, %f}\n"
        "{5 = %f, %f, %f}\n",
        centroids[0].xyz[0], centroids[0].xyz[1], centroids[0].xyz[2],
        centroids[1].xyz[0], centroids[1].xyz[1], centroids[1].xyz[2],
        centroids[2].xyz[0], centroids[2].xyz[1], centroids[2].xyz[2],
        centroids[3].xyz[0], centroids[3].xyz[1], centroids[3].xyz[2],
        centroids[4].xyz[0], centroids[4].xyz[1], centroids[4].xyz[2],
        centroids[5].xyz[0], centroids[5].xyz[1], centroids[5].xyz[2]);

    // cudaDeviceReset must be called before exiting in order for profiling and
    // tracing tools such as Nsight and Visual Profiler to show complete traces.
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceReset();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceReset failed!");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

// Helper function for using CUDA to add vectors in parallel.
cudaError_t addWithCuda(Node* nodes, Node* centroids, unsigned int* order)
{
    Node* dev_nodes               = 0;
    Node* dev_centroids           = 0;
    unsigned int* dev_order       = 0;

    cudaError_t cudaStatus;

    // Choose which GPU to run on, change this on a multi-GPU system.
    cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(0);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaSetDevice failed!  Do you have a CUDA-capable GPU installed?");
    }

    // Allocate GPU buffers for three vectors (two input, one output)    .
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_nodes, 8 * sizeof(Node));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_centroids, 6 * sizeof(Node));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_order, 24 * sizeof(unsigned int));
    if(cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
      fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
    }

    // Copy input vectors from host memory to GPU buffers.
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_nodes, nodes, 8 * sizeof(Node), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_order, order, 24 * sizeof(unsigned int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if(cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
      fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
    }

    // Launch a kernel on the GPU with one thread for each element.

    dim3 threadsPerBlock(6, 4, 3);
    centroid<<<1, threadsPerBlock >>>(dev_nodes, dev_centroids, dev_order);

    // Check for any errors launching the kernel
    cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "addKernel launch failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
    }

    // cudaDeviceSynchronize waits for the kernel to finish, and returns
    // any errors encountered during the launch.
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code %d after launching addKernel!\n", cudaStatus);
    }

    // Copy output vector from GPU buffer to host memory.
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(centroids, dev_centroids, 6 * sizeof(Node), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
    }

    cudaFree(dev_nodes);
    cudaFree(dev_centroids);

    return cudaStatus;
}
$ nvcc -o t1812 t1812.cu -arch=sm_70
$ ./t1812
{0 = 2.000000, 2.000000, 0.000000}
{1 = 2.000000, 0.000000, 2.000000}
{2 = 4.000000, 2.000000, 2.000000}
{3 = 2.000000, 4.000000, 2.000000}
{4 = 0.000000, 2.000000, 2.000000}
{5 = 2.000000, 2.000000, 4.000000}
$
```

https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions